# Return value and if expression

Tags: ado.net, f#

I have the following code to get a row from SQL database. It returns either a record or None. However, it doesn't return because getLogin has the type of `unit = ()` and there is a warning

> warning FS0020: This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'login option'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, or 'let' to bind the result to a name.

How to resolve the issue? Is it the best way to handle Ado.Net?

```
type login = { userName: string; password: string; downloadDir: string}

let getLogin =
    let conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=......;Integrated Security=SSPI;")

    try
        conn.Open()

        let cmd = new SqlCommand("select * FROM Login where website = 'xxx'", conn)
        cmd.CommandType <- CommandType.Text
        use reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() 
        if (reader.HasRows) then (
            reader.Read() |> ignore
            let userName = reader.GetString(5)
            let password = reader.GetString(6)
            printfn "%s" userName
            Some { userName = userName; password = password; downloadDir = "zzz" }
        )
        else (
            printfn "Cannot find login information."
            None
        )

        conn.Close()
    with
        | :? System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException as sqlEx -> printfn "%A" sqlEx.Message
        | _ -> printfn "Unknown Exception"
```

**Update:**
I've updated the code by Thomas' suggestion.

```
let getLogin =
    use conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=mdyptcafgprd101;Initial Catalog=App;Integrated Security=SSPI;")

    try
        conn.Open()

        let cmd = new SqlCommand("select * FROM app.WebCrawler.LoginLbl where website = 'CTSLink'", conn)
        cmd.CommandType <- CommandType.Text
        use reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() 
        if (reader.HasRows) then (
            reader.Read() |> ignore
            let userName = reader.GetString(5)
            let password = reader.GetString(6)
            Some { userName = userName; password = password; downloadDir = "zzz" }
        )
        else (
            printfn "Cannot find login information."
            None
        )

    with
        | :? System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException as sqlEx -> printfn "%A" sqlEx.Message
        | _ -> printfn "Unknown Exception"
```

However, now it gets the following error on line `| :? System...`.

```
s.fs(31,69): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'a -> login option    
but given a
    'a -> unit    
The type 'login option' does not match the type 'unit'
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `if` expression is followed by another line:

```
if reader.HasRows then
  (...)
else
  (...)
conn.Close()
```

... and so the compiler thinks that you are ignoring the result of `if` and instead returning the result of the last expression, which is `conn.Close()`.

The easiest way to fix this is to use the `use` construct - it automatically disposes of the `conn` value when it comes out of scope, and so you do not need the last line and can just use `if` as the last expression in your code:

```
use conn = (...)
if reader.HasRows then
  (...)
else
  (...)
```

Also, you'll need to return some result in the `with ...` branch - that handles an exception and you either need to raise another exception or return a valid value - in this case, probably `None`.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the code to use `use conn`. However, it has error of `error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'a -> login option    
but given a
    'a -> unit    
The type 'login option' does not match the type 'unit'` on the line of exception handler.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 - you need to make the entries in the exception handler have the same return type as the if or rethrow their own exceptions.  (One good example would be to add `None` after the `printfn`